# dbplyr window function for grouped mutate operations

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, dbplyr

I would like to use `dbplyr`/`dplyr` to create a group-level aggregate variable. Here is the gist of the command:

```
q = tbl_copy %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>%
  mutate(x_agg = min(x))
```

But this produces the following error:
`` Error: Window function `min()` is not supported by this database ``

Oddly, when I use the `summarise()` verb, `min()` works just fine.

```
q = tbl_copy %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>%
  summarise(x_agg = min(x))

q %>% show_query()
<SQL>
SELECT `group_var`, `x`, MIN(`x`) AS `x_agg`
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY `group_var`
```

What am I missing? How do I use `group_by()` with `mutate()` on a copy of a MySQL table?

UPDATE: A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

```
> con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
> copy_to(con, mtcars)
> 
> mtcars2 <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
> mtcars2 %>%
+     select(mpg,cyl) %>%
+     group_by(cyl) %>%
+     mutate(mpg_min = min(mpg))
Error: Window function `min()` is not supported by this database
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support window functions, that's why dbplyr cannot translate your dplyr code into SQL.

When you work with a MySQL DB, the usual workaround is to use nested SQL queries such as this one:

```sql
select yt.*, t.x_agg
from yourtable yt inner join (select group_var, min(x) as x_agg 
                              from yt 
                              group by group_var) t 
                    on yt.group_var = t.group_var
```

You can either send the above query directly to MySQL with `dbGetQuery` or transpose this strategy into dplyr code:

```r
tbl_copy %>% 
  inner_join(tbl_copy %>% 
               group_by(group_var) %>%
               summarise(x_agg = min(x)), by = "group_var")
```

Also note that if your table is small enough, a more direct way is to do everything in memory (I mean: on client side, i.e. in R).

Comment: yup, I gotcha. is it not reasonable to expect `dplyr` to write these subqueries programmatically in the SQL translations? I do groupwise `mutate()` a lot, and I'd love to avoid re-writing my `dplyr` code with a bunch of `left_join()` statements. sort of defeats much of the purpose of using `dplyr` in place of the relational DB.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice if `dplyr` could take care of that! But I don't know if we should expect it... Anyway at some point you always need to write carefully optimized SQL queries, and I don't think that can be done through an automatic translation from another language (especially given the fact that each DBMS has its own implementation of SQL).

Comment: I believe that MySQL now supports window functions. I think it would be asking too much of `dbplyr` to generate SQL to implement window functions on a backend that doesn't support them. Even with window functions, `dplyr` has weaker support than it offers via `dbplyr` (because the backends are doing the heavy lifting). For example, `dbplyr` has `window_frame`, which `dplyr` lacks.